# Grails change request.format?

Tags: grails, groovy, mime-types, content-type, mime

Is there any way to modify `request.format` in a filter or controller?

I'm getting `groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot set read-only property: format` no matter what I try. I need to manage my own content type negotiation in a request-neutral way, so a filter seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *request.format* call is handled by the [RequestMimeTypesApi#getFormat method](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/grails-core/blob/a4ebf48e774b6800a62ba90aafb0f81188038452/grails-plugin-mimetypes/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/api/RequestMimeTypesApi.groovy#L57).  I have not tested this, but think the following would work in a filter or controller:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes

....
request[GrailsApplicationAttributes.CONTENT_FORMAT] = format
```